# Solving a series of equations

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I'm writing a piece of code to translate some data, and I keep banging my head against the wall with a one part of the transformation. I'm not as good at math as I ought to be :)

Say we have a collection of amounts of different types (type is denoted by capital letter):

$A = 100$

$B = 200$

And a collection of conversion from one type to another with a conversion factor:

$C_{A->B} = 0.2$

$C_{B->A} = 0.1$

The amounts are the results of a conversion with the above collection of conversions, and now I want to get back the original values.

I can do that by solving these two equations for A_before and B_before:

$$
A_{before} = \frac{A-(-B_{before}*C_{B->A})}{1-C_{A->B}}
$$
$$
B_{before} = \frac{B-(A_{before}*C_{A->B})}{1-C_{B->A}}
$$

Can I make an equation that gives me the original values (Abefore, Bbefore, ... Zbefore) with any number of amounts (A, B, ... Z) and conversions?

I have tried manually with three and four amounts, cyclic and non-cyclic conversions and solving for A_before and it works fine it seems, but I'm trying to implement this
in a piece of software and I don't know how many amounts and conversions there will be.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to find $(A_\text{before}, B_\text{before})$ given $(A,B)$, or the other way round?

Comment: @hypergeometric yes (Abefore,Bbefore) given (A,B). I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough, please let me know if there's other ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Have posted a solution - hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $x=A_\text{before};y=B_\text{before}$
- $x'=A;  y'=B$
- $\lambda=C_{A\rightarrow B}; \mu=C_{B\rightarrow A}$

From equations given:
$$\begin{align}
\left.
\begin{array}{1}
x&=\dfrac{x'-(-\mu y)}{1-\lambda}\\
y&=\dfrac{y'-\lambda x}{1-\mu}
\end{array}
\right\}\\\\
\left.
\begin{array}{1}
(1-\lambda)x-\mu y&=x'\\
(1-\mu) y+\lambda x&=y'
\end{array}
\right\}\\\\
\left(\begin{matrix}1-\lambda&-\mu\\\lambda&1-\mu\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)
&=\left(\begin{matrix}x'\\y'\end{matrix}\right)\\\\
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)
&=\left(\begin{matrix}1-\lambda&-\mu\\\lambda&1-\mu\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{matrix}x'\\y'\end{matrix}\right)\\
&=\frac 1{1-\lambda-\mu+2\lambda\mu}
\left(\begin{matrix}1-\mu&\mu\\-\lambda&1-\lambda\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}x'\\y'\end{matrix}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, but my missing latex skills have made me miss a set of parenthesis in the equations :'( I'll edit the question right away. I really apologize for that.

Comment: That's OK. Does that mean the equations become $A=A'+B/8$, and   $B=B'+2A/9$ respectively? (" ' " indicate "after")

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I should have made clearer, that the 0.1 and 0.2 conversion rates are just examples. Let me correct that right away.

Comment: I have now - hopefully - made it a little clearer. And I learned some Latex along the way :)

Comment: Solution revised, based on revised equations. Your original pair of equations is not symmetrical, in particular the sign of the second term of the numerator on RHS... you might want to check this again.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It lead me to finding out, that there is more to my problem, than I first realized. I will try to redefine it and return with a new question :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to know it's helpful.